# Plesk and Container with Subdomains

Tags: nginx, jboss, hosting, plesk

How is it possible to setup a subdomain in Plesk to redirect the Request to a container on the system but with a different port.
Example:

JBoss is running on port 8070 and domain.com:8070 shows the application. Now I want to add a subdomain to jboss.domain.com which points to domain.com:8070. I don't need just a redirect. I need a reverse proxy like nginx...but I don't know the right solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to answer the question by myself ;)

- At first you have to install mod_proxy for the Apache Web Server
  under "Server" - "Tools and Settings" -> "General Settings" ->
  "Apache Web Server". Activate "proxy" and "proxy_http".
- Second go to your subdomains "Web Server Settings" and fill in the
  following lines under "Additional directives for HTTP" (assuming that your Docker image runs on port 8070):

> ```
>  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8070/  
>  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8070/
> ```