# how to configure the apache mod_jk in parallel plesk and i want to remove port no 8080

Tags: server, plesk, parallels

Please suggest me how to configure the apache modjk in parallels plesk
http://tools.auditmysite.com:8080/home.action

Comment: Please check this answer 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379934/plesk-and-container-with-subdomains